# Building signed APK in Android Studio always debug version

Tags: android, apk, release

As title suggests, every time I try to "Generate signed APK" from android studio it makes debug build, I have searched and tried and with no luck.
How to build signed release version.

Comment: Could you please tell what you have already tried?

Comment: I read that " there should be a tab that says 'build variants'... click on it and switch everything from 'debug' to 'release'" - I can't find this anywhere

Comment: And "gradlew assembleRelease" but this way it generates unsigned apk

Comment: It is on the left hand side of Android Studio

Comment: So you are building your application with gradle? Would be nice to see that in your question ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought gradle comes by default with Android Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `debuggable false`is in the release buildType in your build.gradle. Then switch the Build Variants from Debug to Release. Build Variants are on the left hand side of Android Studio or go to View -> Tool Window -> Build Variants.

Comment: Finally ! thank you, I couldn't find this menu anywhere

Comment: Since this answer helped you, could you please accept it?

Comment: It works for me!!! Is it possible to add this gradle properties?